# How many fugu can I raise?

Tags: hatch

In *Hatch*, how many fugu can I raise at one time? Am I limited to just one fugu on one device, or is there a way to have multiple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just one per device. Per the Hatch Twitter

Answer (score 0):

Only one as far as I know. I mean I've gotten tired and deleted it and got a different one.

Answer (score -1):

You can have up to five but you must be at 100 trust then you may purchase more fugus in the store. Also, at 100 trust and the full sticker book you can change the season and take your fugu on walks

Comment: I'm not sure what led you to this answer, but as far as I can tell, this is not true.